# Можно ли средствами Java убить дочерние процессы процесса, созданного с помощью ProcessBuilder?

Tags: java, jvm, процесс, multiprocessing

Если создать процесс

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("command");
final Process process = builder.start();
```

то его можно будет убить с помощью: `process.destroy();`

Но что, если этот `command` наплодит кучу других процессов? `process.destroy();` уже будет не в силах убить их. И они останутся в памяти.

При этом, если из командной строки сделать <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, то дочерние процессы тоже завершатся.

В сети много вопросов на эту тему (большинство из них старые) и почти все ответы говорят о том, что это невозможно сделать средствами JVM - нужно обращаться к ОС. Решил задать вопрос, в надежде на то, что это всё же стало возможным с появлением Java 8. Хочется получить решение, не зависимое от ОС.

Возможно ли на сегодняшний день средствами Java убить дочерние процессы процесса, созданного с помощью `ProcessBuilder`, не манипулируя напрямую с командами ОС? Если возможно, то как это реализовать? Если нет, то ожидается ли такая возможность в Java 9?

#### UPDATE

Хочу ещё раз выделить то, что я не ищу решения, зависящие от ОС. По [этой ссылке](http://www.golesny.de/p/code/javagetpid) можно прочитать о том, как искать PID процесса в Unix и Windows. Потом можно будет обратиться к терминалу с соответствующей командой для "убийства" процесса.

Это не является темой данного вопроса.

Comment: Не думаю. Это всё же уровень ОС. Не очень в плане безопасности, если jvm будет иметь доступ к таким вещам.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В версиях Java до 8й включительно инструментарий для работы с процессами был довольно скудным.

Но если ознакомиться, с [JEP 102: Process API Updates](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/102) (который реализуется в рамках Java 9), то мы увидим, что Brian Goetz говорит нам о следующих вещах:

1. Возможность получить pid процесса JVM и pid-ы процессов, запущенных средствами API.
2. Возможность получить список запущенных в системе процессов, включая их pid, состояние, наименование и, возможно, потребление ресурсов.
3. Возможность взаимодействовать с деревьями процессов, а именно прекращать работу целого дерева.
4. Возможность взаимодействовать с сотнями дочерних процессов, возможно, мультиплексируя потоки вывода и ошибок, чтобы избежать создания отдельной нити (thread) на каждый процесс.

Все эти радости уже можно потрогать в 9ке: см. интерфейс [`ProcessHandle`](http://download.java.net/jdk9/docs/api/index.html?java/lang/ProcessHandle.html):

1. `long getPid()`
2. `static Stream<ProcessHandle> allProcesses()` и `ProcessHandle.Info info()`
3. `Stream<ProcessHandle> descendants()`

Answer (score 4):

Если речь идет о "популярных" ОС для Java (Windows & unix-like), то на первой можно запустить программу [taskkill](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491009.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)`/PID <pid>`, а на вторых - [kill](http://linux.die.net/man/2/kill)`-9 <pid>`. На юниксе, кроме того, можно отправить сигнал *группе процессов* (process group id равен -<pid> процесса-родоначальника группы.

Или воспользоваться библиотекой, дергающей нативные методы, типа [Posix for Java](http://www.bmsi.com/java/posix/index.html) (впрочем, для метода [kill](http://linux.die.net/man/2/kill) достаточно простого JNI вызова. Но средствами именно Java, да без сторонних библиотек, насколько я знаю, нет.

<s>Правда, [говорят](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750470/how-to-get-pid-of-process-ive-just-started-within-java-program), что у `Process` так просто pid не получишь, но вот можно через Reflection достать приватное поле UnixProcess'а pid.. :)</s>

В 9-ой версии OpenJDK `Process` имеет метод [getPid()](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/dev/jdk/file/db013eafc5c3/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/Process.java#l345), так что, теперь вышла нам всем поблажка в плане получения `pid`. Однако, никаких переносимых методов для управления группой процессов пока не просматривается.

Comment: Мне интересно решение без ручного вызова `kill`. Всё же у Java есть девиз "Write once, run everywhere".

Comment: А, вас смутил тэг Linux. Я его поставил, чтобы в худшем случае получить решение для него. Но желательно, конечно, не отправлять команды в ОС вручную.

Comment: Убрал тэг Linux.

Comment: Ну, если руководствоваться девизами... ;) Практически же, если проблема и вправду актуальна, придется городить библиотеку с нативом, увы.

Comment: А если я через рефлексию буду убивать процесс (точнее, через `kill`), как это отразится в работе GC? Соберётся ли `Process` автоматически? Ведь `destroy()` не запустится.

Comment: Погодите, те процессы, которые были запущены вашим _дочерним процессом_ - они _вне_ JVM и для них нет никаких соответствующих структур в JVM. Так что, по поводу "внучат" вообще не следует беспокоиться. По поводу "ребенка" - да, в JVM могут быть структуры, которые отслеживают его состояние. Однако, после завершения процесса эти структуры точно так же освобождаются, вне зависимости от того, как закончилась жизнь дочернего процесса, штатно или через сигнал. Так что, .destroy() совсем не обязателен и ничего не должно утечь.

Comment: Я уточнил вопросы и добавил конкурс. Буду благодарен, если примите участие. Нужно будет добавить в ответ информацию о кроссплатформенном решении

Answer (score 2):

Кроссплатформенного решения нету. Придётся писать для каждой ОС самому. Не так всё просто, по-этому вряд ли кто-то даст законченное решение. Мы можем только дать какие-то подсказки, пути к решению задачи.

## Unix

Сначала надо получить PID нашего процесса.

```
/**
 * Получить строку - pid программы - Java VM
 */
public static String getPid() throws IOException,InterruptedException {

  Vector<String> commands=new Vector<String>();
  commands.add("/bin/bash");
  commands.add("-c");
  commands.add("echo $PPID");
  ProcessBuilder pb=new ProcessBuilder(commands);

  Process pr=pb.start();
  pr.waitFor();
  if (pr.exitValue()==0) {
    BufferedReader outReader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream()));
    return outReader.readLine().trim();
  } else {
    System.out.println("Error while getting PID");
    return "";
  }
}
```

С другой стороны `java.lang.Process` - абстрактный класс, конкретная реализация зависит от ОС. На Linux это `java.lang.UnixProcess`, у которой есть приватное поле `pid`. Используя рефлексию можно запросто получить поле:

```
public static long getPidOfProcess(Process p) {
    long pid = -1;

    try {
      if (p.getClass().getName().equals("java.lang.UNIXProcess")) {
        Field f = p.getClass().getDeclaredField("pid");
        f.setAccessible(true);
        pid = f.getLong(p);
        f.setAccessible(false);
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      pid = -1;
    }
    return pid;
  }
```

Дальше необходимо получить список подпроцессов.

Есть комманда `pstree ${pid}`.

Можно выполнить команду из Java

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("pstree ${pid}");
```

Затем спарсить список и вытащить PID'ы всех процессов. Потом используя `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` убить все процессы по PID'ам, если надо.

## Windows

Для получения PID'а можно сделать что-то [такое](http://www.golesny.de/p/code/javagetpid).

Тут сложнее. Я знаю, что можно получить список запущенных процессов.

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c tasklist");
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
IOUtils.copy(p.getInputStream(), writer);
String theString = writer.toString();
```

Но вопрос как найти зависимости между процессами не ясен.

Как минимум, можно выполнить `tasklist` и отфильтровать список по имени процесса. Процесс с большим PID вероятно и есть ваш процесс. Так вы получите PID вашего главного процесса.

Можно попробовать запустить PowerShell скрипт для получения списка процессов (а потом отфильтровать по parent id).

Такая команда в шеле:

```
gwmi win32_process |select ProcessID,ParentProcessID,Name, @{l="Username";e={$_.getowner().user}}|where {$_.Username -ne "SYSTEM"} | where {$_.Username -ne "LOCAL SERVICE"} | where {$_.Username -ne "NETWORK SERVICE"} | where {$_.Username -ne $null} |Sort-Object ProcessID | ft -AutoSize
```

Даст что-то такое:

```
ProcessID ParentProcessID Name                     Username
--------- --------------- ----                     --------
      180            4536 chrome.exe               Suvitruf
      396            5272 slack.exe                Suvitruf
     1488            1040 taskeng.exe              Suvitruf
     1504            4008 BatteryLife.exe          Suvitruf
     1540             180 chrome.exe               Suvitruf
     1704             180 chrome.exe               Suvitruf
     2084             180 chrome.exe               Suvitruf
     2404            5272 slack.exe                Suvitruf
     2408            5272 slack.exe                Suvitruf
```

Вам надо понять как эту команду выполнить с использованием `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()`.

После этого распарсить ответ и получить список PID'ов процессов.

Для их убийства вызывать:

```
String cmd = "taskkill /F /PID " + tokill;
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

Comment: Для начала, хотелось бы поблагодарить за такой труд. Я тоже нашёл [реализацию на разных ОС](http://www.golesny.de/p/code/javagetpid). Но вопрос не в этом. Мне нужно кроссплатформенное решение, если такое есть. Если нет, то нужно указать причины со ссылками на официальные или же надёжные источники. Так же нужно ответить на вопрос о том, ожидается ли поддержка этой функциональности в ближайшем будущем.

Comment: @LEQADA я не встречал кроссплатформенных решений. Как и не видел инфы о том, что в Java 9 что-то такое собираются сделать.

Comment: @LEQADA разве создание собственного класса, реализующего данную функциональность в разных ОС, не является кроссплатформенным решением? Или вы ищите какое-то готовое решение, которое будет работать само, без капли труда с вашей стороны?

Comment: @IgorKudryashov, у Java есть такой девиз "Write once, run everywhere". Это означает, что виртуальная машина всю кроссплатформенность обеспечивает за разработчика. Вот об этой кроссплатформенности я и спрашиваю. Делать свой класс на все случаи жизни можно, наверное, но зачем, если виртуальная машина умеет это делать за вас?

Comment: @LEQADA ну вот, как видите "не умеет", т.е. не всё умеет. Мне кажется ничего страшного нет в своём классе, написан он вами или кем-то другим - всё равно же вы используете какие-то библиотеки в своём проекте - будет ещё одной больше. Ну, если конечно, у вас там не какая-то особая JVM с кучей различных ограничений на всё подряд.

Comment: @IgorKudryashov, то, что Вы не знаете или не встречали такого решения, ещё не означает, что его не может быть. Если у вас есть весомые аргументы, доказывающие невозможность такой функциональности в Java - приведите их и получите 125 очков репутации и благодарность от меня, а ещё кучу очков репутации и благодарности от других пользователей. Эта тема поднималась на SO многократно. И каждый раз всё завершалось тем, что кто-то приводил решение, зависимое от ОС. Целью этого вопроса является поиск чётких ответов на непонятные моменты.

Comment: @LEQADA вам дали ответ, сейчас jvm не поддерживает этого и не планирует в будущем.

Comment: @Suvitruf, прочитайте, пожалуйста, комментарий конкурса. Он находится непосредственно под телом вопроса - там, где есть информация о конкурсе.

Comment: @LEQADA то есть, вы заведомо задали вопрос, ответы на который перманентно отметаете. Создали конкурс. Ну да ладно. Приз всё равно уйдёт тому ответу, у которого больше голосов. Удачи.

Comment: @Suvitruf, я поблагодарил за ответ. Но вы не поняли моего вопроса. Я даже обновление добавил в тело вопроса, чтобы не было недопониманий. Я всё ещё надеюсь на то, что кто-то сможет ответить именно на поставленные вопросы.

Comment: @Suvitruf, не соглашусь с "и не планирует в будущем".

Comment: @Nofate я в анонсах ничего подобного не встречал. Если у вас информация есть на этот счёт, прошу поделиться.

Comment: @Suvitruf, см. мой ответ

Comment: @Nofate благодарю.