# Можно ли закрыть процесс в системе windows java

Tags: java

Интересует такой вопрос можно ди допустим закрыть диспетчер задач или другое приложение в Windows.

Пытался найти какую-то информацию в интернете, но что-то слабо ищется

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7473589 оно?   попроще: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11366828

Comment: Посмотрите [этот вопрос на ruSO](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/468199/). Коротко, в java-9 (где-то через год) будет расширенное api для работы с процессами, в котором можно будет, а пока обходитесь jni/вызовом команд/сторонними библиотеками.